# ¿Cómo se hace callback en una directiva en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo el siguiente problema, al intentar de llamar a una función que se le pasa a una directiva y agregarle unos parámetros me devuelve un error.

#### Directiva

```
angular
  .module('my.directive', [])
  .directive('myInput', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        change: '&?',
      },
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="myinput" aria-label="format" autocomplete="off" />',
      link: function (scope, element) {
        // on change function
        if (typeof scope.change === 'function') {
          element.on('change', function () {
            // acá es donde quiero pasarle parámetros
            scope.change('asdText', true, 829232)
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }])
```

#### Vista

```
<my-input change="myFunction" />
```

#### Controlador

```
angular
  .module('my.directive', [])
  .directive('myControllerDirective', [function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'myTemplateUrl.html',
      controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.myFunction = function(param1, param2, param3) {
          // hacer algo con esos parámetros
        };
      }]
    }
  }])
```

---

Esto es en **Angular 1.6**. El error que me arroja es:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for
>   'myFunction' in asdText

Agrego un [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJLMob?editors=1011) para poder visualizarlo.

Comment: Te has dejado lo más importante fuera, creo... ese error siempre tiene el formato `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'x' in 'y'`. Ese 'y' sería lo importante

Comment: No, no me tira ese texto el error. Pero si, tiene que ver algo con eso, quiero creer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de muchas vueltas, logré hacerlo, simplemente tuve que pasarle la función a una variable para luego llamarla con los parámetros deseados.

```js
angular
  .module('my.directive', [])
  .directive('myInput', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        change: '&?',
      },
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="myinput" aria-label="format" autocomplete="off" />',
      link: function (scope, element) {
        // on change function
        if (typeof scope.change === 'function') {
          element.on('change', function () {
            console.log('on change input')
            // asigno la función a una variable
            var changeFunction = scope.change()
            
            // acá es donde quiero pasarle parámetros
            changeFunction('asdText', true, 829232)
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }])
  .directive('myControllerDirective', [function () {
    return {
      template: '<my-input change="myFunction" />',
      controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.myFunction = function(param1, param2, param3) {
          // hacer algo con esos parámetros
          console.log(param1, param2, param3)
        };
      }]
    }
  }])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="my.directive">
  <my-controller-directive />
</body>
```